# Firebase android: Getting invalid appcheck token error even though SHA 256 fingerprint is registered in console

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

I am trying to implement `Firebase app check` in my android app. I have followed all the steps as shown in the [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider).

- I am using Firebase BoM libraries as shown in the documentation page:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'
}
```

- I got my `SHA 256` fingerprint which I got from android studio after running this command in the terminal:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

- I added the fingerprint in both `PlayIntegrity` and `SafetyNet` attestations (just in case `PlayIntegrity` doesn't work)
- Inside all the activities in my app, I added this code:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(activity_name.this);
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
        PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());


FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

mAuth.signInAnonymously()
        .addOnCompleteListener(record_viewer.this, (OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>) task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) { 

                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

                //rest of the code here
            }
        });
```

Every time I run my app on my physical device, I get these warnings in my console:

```
 pc_0 - Detected invalid AppCheck token. Reconnecting (2 attempts remaining)
 pc_0 - Detected invalid AppCheck token. Reconnecting (1 attempts remaining)
 pc_0 - Detected invalid AppCheck token. Reconnecting (0 attempts remaining)
 pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect.   Reason: Invalid appcheck token
```

How is my appcheck token invalid? I have tried regenerating and reattaching my `SHA 256` fingerprint again and again into my `Playintegrity` attestation (thinking the key might be wrong), but this warning keeps on reappearing.
Where am I going wrong?

---

**EDIT :** Ok, I've noticed this line in the documentation page:

> Currently, the built-in Play Integrity provider only supports Android apps distributed by Google Play. To use Play Integrity's off-Play features, or to use App Check with your own custom provider, see Implement a custom App Check provider.

Does this mean I have to publish the app in Google play store for the `PlayIntegrity` attestation to work?